# force Time.format(...) to use local resources in android

Tags: android, time, android-resources

`android.text.format.Time` uses System resources for getting month names, week days, etc. Now, I want to use my app in a locale that translations for that locale does not exist by default. Suppose I want to set custom names for weekdays. So, how can I use `Time.format(...)` method? How can I force it to use my resources instead of System's.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom formats using either [android.text.format.DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html) or [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The latter lets you pass a custom [DateFormatSymbols](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) object, which should allow you to define your own names for months and weekdays, etc.